# how to save result from for loop in variable

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

```
y = Data_read.loc[:, ((Data_read == 0) | (Data_read == 1) ).all()]
a = pd.isna(Data_read)

for parameter in y:
    aa = {}
    aa[parameter] = aa
    aa = 'binary parameter =' , parameter
    print(aa)
for parameter in a:
   if a[parameter].any() == True or parameter in y:
         bb = 'Invalid Parameter = ', parameter
         print(bb)
   
         
   else:
      cc = 'Valid Parameter = ', parameter
      print(cc)
```

When I try to print the value for `aa` I only get one variable in result, how can I save all the variables from loop in `aa`.

Comment: Remove `aa = 'binary parameter =' , parameter` and just print it.

Answer (score 2):

You have two problems in your code.

1. You are overriding the `aa` variable on this line:

   aa = 'binary parameter =' , parameter

Initially, you declared aa to be a set, but now you set it to something else. You have to use another variable name.

2. You redefine the `aa` variable at the start of each for loop on this line:

   aa = {}

Again it creates the same problem. Every time for loop runs, you start with an empty dictionary. You must move this line out of the for-loop